# Regex Expression Incorrect Output

Tags: c#, regex

Hey guys I'm trying to create a regex function in C# which will search a sentence for all words ending in "es". I'm trying to get the output to be in the  format of

```
Word1 = bes
Word2 = mes
Word3 = ces
```

and so on. The problem is that the I keep getting "errorCS0136" upon compilation. I tried using `Console.WriteLine()` and having a counter variable increment on each iteration of the loop but that wouldn't work. Here is a copy of the errors I'm getting. Thanks so much.

> Task1.cs(66,52): error CS1026: Unexpected symbol ',', expecting ')'
>
> Task1.cs(66,55): error CS0136: A local variable named 'match' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'match', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
>
> Task1.cs(66,59): error CS1026: Unexpected symbol ')', expecting ')'
>
> Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings

Below is my source code.

```
public void numPatternSearch(){
    string input3;
    string pattern = @"\b\w+es\b";
    //Regex regex = new Regex("[*]");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter string to search: ");
    input3 = Console.ReadLine();
    //input3 = string.Join("", input3.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    //input3 = Regex.Match(input3, @"\d+").Value;
    //string[] substrings = regex.Split(input3);
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input3, pattern)){
        int count = 1;
        string[] substrings = "Number"+count+" = '{0}'", match;
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine(substrings);
        }
    //Console.WriteLine(input3);
    }
}
```

Comment: `string[] substrings = "Number"+count+" = '{0}'", match;` is invalid syntax, you should create a capture group in the regex around the word you're matching (e.g. `@"\b(\w+es)\b"`)and then use `match.Groups[1].Value` to get the word.

Comment: The above compile errors are caused by code elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler error occurs in that line:

```
string[] substrings = "Number"+count+" = '{0}'", match;
```

That's not valid c#. If you want a list of the resulting strings, you can try this:

```
List<string> substrings = new List<string>();
int count = 1;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input3, pattern))
{
    string substring = string.Format("Number{0} = '{1}'", count, match);
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine(substring);
    substrings.Add(substring);
 }
```

You can now use `substrings` for further operations. You can convert the `List<string>` into an array using

```
string[] subStringArray = substrings.ToArray();
```

Note that I declared `count` outside the loop. Otherwise you would always use `1` as count!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a compilation error. Your code is never run.

The error is saying it's on line 66, which I assume is this one:

```
string[] substrings = "Number"+count+" = '{0}'", match;
```

This isn't valid C#. I'm not exactly sure what you want. An array can be initialized like this:

```
string[] substrings = ["Number"+countString+" = '{0}'", otherString]; // where otherString needs to be a string
```

It looks more like you are trying to call Format.

Comment: I'm not gonna write my own answer but seems like he's trying to use string.Format there.

Answer (score 1):

Modified Version of your Source Code:

```
    public void numPatternSearch()
    {
        string input3;
        string pattern = @"\b\w+es\b";
        Console.WriteLine("Enter string to search: ");
        input3 = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] substrings = new string[100];
        int count = 1;
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input3, pattern))
        {
            substrings[count - 1] = string.Format("Number" + count + " = {0}", match);
            Console.WriteLine(substrings[count - 1]);
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What if there are 101 matches?